VS Code autocomplete suggest indirect imports Flutter/Dart
vscode autocomplete suggests not only the source of the file, but all files where this import is used.
I have a GoalStatus type and use it in several files. When creating a new view, vscode confused where to import as in the picture

vscode Version: 1.96.0 (Universal)
Dart SDK version: 3.5.4 (stable) on "macos_arm64"
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 14.7 23H124 darwin-arm64)
